# Overriding copy.deepcopy() for builtin type in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, overriding, deep-copy, built-in-types

I want a deep copy of a large data structure, but I want to handle objects of type `bytes` in a different way. Basically, if it can be decoded as UTF-8, I want to copy it as a string, otherwise I want to calculate a hash and copy *that* instead of the real value. Seems like it ought to be easy enough to implement.

If `bytes` were a class I had control over, I could rewrite its `__deepcopy__` function, but I don't. I also don't have the ability to make these objects a different class instead of `bytes` without a significant amount of effort, which I'm trying to avoid. Getting `deepcopy` to work in a different way seemed like a reasonable choice.

I tried to make a new class inheriting from `copy`, assuming `deepcopy` fell back on `copy` once it found a leaf node, but it's not implemented as a class. (I don't think my assumption was correct either.) I can't just implement a new function and fall back on `deepcopy` if the argument isn't a `bytes` object, because it'll never come back out to use my logic once it goes in.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem in a reasonably easy way?

Comment: Decoding attributes makes it sound like you don't really want a copy. What's the reasoning behind this decoding? There might be a better way (eg. you could just copy the actual class, and then afterwards perform your decoding). This might come with some overhead but if it's negligible then its probably better to go that route and save yourself the headache of defining a new copy mechanism.

Comment: @Kraigolas It's a relatively complex data structure that's pulled from an external source. There probably aren't any recursive references or anything like that, but it's lots of arrays inside dictionaries inside dictionaries, etc., and the values are all returned as bytes objects, despite actually being timestamps, strings, images, etc. (It's actually from an LDAP database.) I'm looking to compare multiple versions of this data structure to find differences. I'm trying to use DeepDiff, but it's breaking on actual binary data. (I have a bug open on that, but I'm trying to work around it.)

Comment: FWIW, I wasn't able to solve this and worked around DeepDiff's issue by creating a custom handler for DeepDiff instead. It still feels like it would be nice to be able to use `deepcopy`'s traversal algorithm for other things.